# Require argument only if another argument is set

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a Python command that has an option which, if used, requires two arguments.  One argument is a string, and the other is a list of one or more strings.  It would be really nice if the command syntax could look something like this:

```
mycommand requiredarg [optionalarg optList...]
```

I know I can set `nargs='?'` for `optionalarg` and `nargs='*'` for `optList` to get a similar result, but that would allow one to be set and the other not.

```
mycommand 'thing'  # Good
mycommand 'thing' 'ama'  # Should be an error
mycommand 'thing' 'ama' 'bob'  # Good
mycommand 'thing' 'ama' 'bob' 's'  # Good
```

Is there a way to do this in argparse?

Comment: If you aren't using flagged arguments (`optionals`), it might be simpler to just look at `sys.argv` and allocate the strings yourself.